# Smooth scrolling doesnt work with element.scrollIntoView

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function that runs when the person scrolls which scrolls them directly to a section of website (in this case its "downarrow").

Function:

```
function scroll_to_target(){
const element = document.getElementById("downarrow");
element.scrollIntoView({
behavior: "auto"
        });
       }
```

Trigger:

```
        var scrollPosition = $("body, html").scrollTop()
        var element = document.getElementById("downarrow");
        var hasScrolled = false;
        window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
        if (scrollPosition == 0 && !hasScrolled) {
            //element.scrollIntoView("downarrow");
            hasScrolled = true;
            scroll_to_target()
        }
        }
```

The code above works perfectly fine but i want it to not scroll instantly and rather scroll slowly and smoothly. So I change the behavior: "auto" to behavior: "smooth" in the function and try again but it doesnt work. However, when i put this function to a button it works smoothly but nothing happens when user scrolls.

Comment: Can you precisely describe what you mean by: _"when the person scrolls"_? Do you mean they use the scroll wheel of the mouse? Use touch, or?

Comment: When the person uses the scroll wheel of the mouse

Comment: this is usually due to stack order in javascript you can use `setTimeout(() => element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })` to solve it

Comment: you can also delay to 20ms or 70ms if it doesn't work

Comment: when i put the "setTimeout(scroll_to_target, 70) ; element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });" code in the function itself it works (it enters a loop and makes you scroll down infinitely which is not what i want) and when i put it in the if statement it does not work